# ReactiveCocoa 4.0 :- Unable to map the NSURLSession.sharedSession().rac_dataWithRequest

Tags: ios, swift2, reactive-cocoa

I got a warning when i using reactive cocoa web service request.

> Result of call to 'on(started:event:failed:completed:interrupted:terminated:disposed:next:)' is unused: Did you forget to call `start` on the producer?

**Code:**

```
    func callwebservice(dataDictionary:[String: String]? , urlString: String){
    print("******* dictionary = \(dataDictionary)")
    let boundary = "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string: urlString)!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let body = NSMutableData();
    if dataDictionary != nil {
        for (key, value) in dataDictionary! {
            body.appendData(NSString(format:"--\(boundary)\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            body.appendData(NSString(format:"\(value)\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            body.appendData(NSString(format:"--\(boundary)\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

        }
    }
    request.HTTPBody=body

    let requestType =  NSURLSession.sharedSession().rac_dataWithRequest(request)
    requestType.on(started: {
        print("Started")
        }, event: { event in
            print("Event: \(event)")
        }, failed: { error in
            print("Failed: \(error)")
        }, completed: {
            print("Completed")
        }, interrupted: {
            print("Interrupted")
        }, terminated: {
            print("Terminated")
        }, disposed: {
            print("Disposed")
        }, next: { value in
            print("Next: \(value)")
    })
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.start()` to get a Signal. Right now it's just a SignalProducer. Add `.start()` after the `on(…)` call.

Comment: I rewrite the code in this way it works now requestType
            .start { (event) in
                switch event {
                case .Next(let user):
                    print(user)
                    observer.sendCompleted()
                case .Failed(let error):
                    observer.sendFailed(error)
                default:
                    observer.sendCompleted()
                }
        }

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking for confirmation about your code or telling me it didn't work, because that code is not what I suggested.

Comment: I know that, but I solved the problem , and thanks for your suggestion.